# Admissble type role overrides

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, coercion, newtype

In GHC Haskell, `Map k v` has a [type role](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/roles.html) declaration for `k` to be nominal. This is because the user can otherwise `coerce` `k` to another type with the same representation but different `Ord` instance, breaking the invariants.

However, I have some newtypes whose `Ord` instances are inherited. In this case `unsafeCoerce` seems to do the job (correct me if there are subtleties I don't know), but this completely turns off the typechecking for the coercion, which keeps me awake at night. In my specific use case, I have a type `MyWrapper k`, and I would like to be able to declare some newtypes `k1` -> `k2` as admissible for safe coercion even when it is the argument of `MyWrapper`. Is this possible? What are some other workarounds?

Comment: Isn't coercing the key you want to lookup more sensical than coercing the entire `Map`? This probably is more safe.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem Wouldn't that mean I have to carry `(Coercible k1 k2)` in a lot of places, since I don't actually know the type in the intermediate calculations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it makes sense to introduce a typeclass for this specific purpose. Not to actually do the conversion, just to alias a version of `unsafeCoerce` restricted to the case where it actually is safe.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class (Ord a, Ord b) => CompatibleOrd a b
  -- no methods

instance CompatibleOrd YourBaseType YourNewtype

coerceKeysMonotonically :: (Coercible a b, CompatibleOrd a b)
          => Map a y -> Map b y
coerceKeysMonotonically = unsafeCoerce
```

Comment: Maybe `Coercible` should be a superclass of `CompatibleOrd`? I feel that makes the class more meaningful. (`CompatibleOrd a b` can then mean "the ordering on `a` induced by `coerce`ing the ordering on `b` is the same as the natural ordering on `a`, and vice versa". I don't see what it really means now.)

Comment: @HTNW I think this additionally allows injective monotonic unsafeCoerce, which is nice to know but I don't know if there's ause case

Answer (score 0):

I created a ticket that proposed this: "Make coerce-derived dictionaries coercible"

https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/20815